# Knockout JS foreach nested, value updates in all fields

Tags: foreach, knockout.js

I am using knockout js to acheive a task. My model is like:

```
var ServiceLevelRates = function(data, availableClasses) {
return {
    TaxTypeID: ko.observable(data.Key),
    TaxTypeName: ko.observable(data.Name),
    ExtendedTaxTypeName: data.Name.replace(/\s+/g, ''),
    ApplyAfter: ko.observable(-1),
    TaxClasses: ko.observableArray(availableClasses)
};
};

var TaxClass = function(data, availableServices) {
return {
    ServiceClassID: data.ServiceClassID,
    ServiceClassName: ko.observable(data.ServiceClassName),
    TaxServices: ko.observableArray(availableServices)
};
};

var TaxService = function(data) {
return {
    ServiceID: ko.observable(data.ServiceID),
    ServiceName: ko.observable(data.ServiceName),
    ServiceRate: ko.observable(data.ServiceRate > 0 ? data.ServiceRate : "").extend({ numeric: 2 })
};
};
```

and my html is like:

```
<tbody  data-bind="foreach: ServiceLevelRates">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100%;">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:2%;">
                                        <img src="../../Images/del_up.gif" onclick="HideMyChilds(this);" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-bind="text: TaxTypeName">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width:20%;">
                                                    <label id="lblApplyAfter"  myId="lblApplyAfter" runat="server">Apply After</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select id="sltApplyAfter" SkinID="drpFields" name="sltApplyAfter" runat="server" myId="sltApplyAfter">
                                                        <option value="-1">Charge</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" />Apply for All Services<input type="text" onkeypress="ValidateDecimalValue(event,this)"; onblur="ApplyForAllServices(this);" data-bind="attr: { 'class': ExtendedTaxTypeName }"  /> %
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <table width="100%">
                                                        <tbody  data-bind="foreach: TaxClasses">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="width:2%;">
                                                                    <img src="../../Images/del_up.gif" onclick="HideMyChilds(this);" />
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width:100%;" class="tdRepeaterHeaderBG" data-bind="text: ServiceClassName">

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <table width="100%">
                                                                        <thead>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="width:1%;">
                                                                                <td style="width:24%;" class="tdRepeaterHeaderBG">Service Name</td>
                                                                                <td style="width:75%;" class="tdRepeaterHeaderBG">Amount</td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </thead>
                                                                        <tbody  data-bind="foreach: TaxServices">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="width:1%;">
                                                                                <td style="width:24%;" data-bind="text: ServiceName"></td>
                                                                                <td style="width:75%;">
                                                                                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: ServiceRate, attr: { 'class': $parents[1].ExtendedTaxTypeName, 'id': $parents[1].ExtendedTaxTypeName + ServiceID }"  />%
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td></td>
                                                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                                                    <div style="font-size: 11px; width:98%;height:5px; border-top: 1px dotted gray;"> </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

The problem is when I provide ServiceRate for a taxservice in one class, it is updated into text field of same service in all other classes. Any help on it will be great.

Comment: Maybe you can try to reproduce this in a jsFiddle?  Here was a start: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/T89GH/

Comment: Can you show us the javascript where you create your viewmodels and then bind them to the page?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Thanks a lot for this start but I am not able to produce it there :( However if you can help me in another issue I am facing, if you check the jsFiddle we have a textbox saying 'Apply for All Services', on its blur I am calling a method 'ApplyForAllServices' which I have copied in the jsFiddle, locally with me this method copies the value in the child text boxes but the KO View Model doesn't get updated, can you please help me out in it? I am new to KO, sorry if asking childish things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ImranBalouch - generally you will want to bind your checkbox against an observable on your view model and react to it changing. Here is a sample that is similar to what you are doing: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/nLXSk/.  Then you don't have to add your own handlers.  Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Thanks a lot, I will try to follow your guide line.

Comment: @CodeThug  I have tried to put it on jsfiddle but I am new to jsfiddle, so couldn't find the problems in it. I have placed it at http://jsfiddle.net/ikbalouch/aAx8X/

Comment: @RPNiemeyer the subscribe solution has worked great, thanks a lot for this help, can you please look into fiddle I shared in my last post that where and what I am doing wrong, for my original problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ikbalouch/aAx8X/  here is the working scenario of my problem, can you guys please guide me that whats I am doing wrong.

Comment: @ImranBalouch - looks like you found your solution. Let me know if you still have outstanding questions.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Thanks a lot sir, I am done with this series of questions, if I get any will contact you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code have several issues.

1. First, mostly a cosmetic one. You are using tables for layout. They should only be used when you truly need tabular data. Div's or lists are much better in most cases, and if you need to layout something, you could use css margins.
2. You are mixing, and mixing up, different object schemes.

   - One is to return an object literal:

     ```
     function Foo() {
         return {
             Property: ko.observable(),
         }
     }
     ```

     This schema could, but shouldn't, be called with the `new` operator.
   - The other one is prototype-based:

     ```
     function Foo() {
         var self = this;

         self.Property = ko.observable();
     }
     ```

     This schema must be called with the `new` operator.

   It is easiest to stick to one schema. With knockout, the latter is easier to use in some cases.
3. You are not using observables for all properties. It is a little confusing to be using observables for some properties, and not for others. You have to go back to the source-code to confirm for each property.
4. Your object model does not take into account object reuse. You are passing the same objects to each `ServiceLevelRate`, so when you are updating one `TaxService`, the same `TaxService` in all other `TaxClass` will also be updated.

   One simple solution for this, is to factor out the fields that needs updating into mapping objects.

   ```
   // This part is constructed once, based on server data.
   function TaxService(data) {
       var self = this;

       self.ServiceID = ko.observable(data.ServiceID);
       self.ServiceName = ko.observable(data.ServiceName);
   }

   // This part is constructed for each TaxClassMapping
   function TaxServiceMapping(svc) {
       var self = this;

       self.TaxService = ko.observable(svc);
       self.ServiceRate = ko.observable("");
   }
   ```
5. Lastly; To conditionally update the rates based on the check-box, you can bind the it with the `checked`-binding. In the subscription for the `ServiceLevelRate`-wide rate, you just check if the check-box was checked, before proceeding to update the other fields.

   ```
   self.ApplyForAll.subscribe(function (newValue) {
       if (self.ApplyForAllCheckBox()) {
           ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Classes(), function (clsMapping) {
               ko.utils.arrayForEach(clsMapping.ClassServices(), function (svcMapping) {
                   svcMapping.ServiceRate(newValue);
               });
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/V8DTj/

I scaled down the models to the essential parts, to make them easier to work with.

---

To make the `TaxServices` show only for certain `TaxClasses`, you could filter which `TaxService`-objects you want to include for each `TaxClass`.

```
function TaxClassMapping(taxClass, availableServices) {
    var self = this;

    self.TaxClass = ko.observable(taxClass);

    var classID = taxClass.ServiceClassID();
    var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(availableServices, function (svc) {
        // svc.ServiceClassID is a new property in TaxService
        return svc.ServiceClassID() === classID;
    });
    var mapped = ko.utils.arrayMap(filtered, function (svc) {
        return new TaxServiceMapping(svc);
    });
    self.ClassServices = ko.observableArray(mapped);
}
```

Comment: Markus! Thanks a lot for the detailed analysis and tips and solutions, sorry for being late in replying. I am going to work on your guidelines now.

Comment: ! if I introduce ServiceClassID in otaxServices array and I want to Services to appear under corresponding class, what approach I must follow?